# express js not performing last function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use app.get in order to run functions in a sequence. For the following example, I want to run function "f" after function "t". However, I only get the output from function "t" and not "f" when I run the code. I'm new to express and node js, so I would appreciate any help!

```
 function t(req, res){
    //stuff

  };

  function f(){
    console.log('hi');
  };

  app.get('/test', t, f);
```

basically, i'm not getting "hi" in my console. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add another parameter `next` to the function `t`. It will essentially make the function `t` a **middleware callback**. The line **`next()`** is crucial since it passes execution to the next callback provided in the servers lifecycle.

```js
function t(req, res, next){
   //stuff
   next();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this helped. however, t gets data from an API, so it takes longer to run than f. i was wondering if there was a way to make sure f happens only when t completes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @GiddharthSupta said, you need to pass the `next` parameter to the function `t` what it does is that, after performing its own execution, it passes the control to next function